# WPF Элемент со своими аргументами

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Проблема скорее не в том, что у меня не получается, а в том, как правильно сделать

Мне нужно создать ProgressBar, который имеет в себе текст и свойство быть скрытым, я хотел написать стиль для прогрессбара, но как я понял, просто так передать в стиль эти аргументы не получится. Как будет правильнее сделать? Способ с созданием элемента мне как-то не симпотизирует

1. Создать свой элемент (как это сделать я вроде понял, тут пояснений
   не надо)
2. Стиль для прогрессбара (подскажите, как передать аргументы или объект со всеми свойствами)
3. Стиль для какого-то элемента, в который можно передать объект, как с элементом списка (подскажите, как называется этот элемент)

Comment: Это называется `UserControl`. Делайте свой, в него помещайте все что вам надо, делайте `DependencyProperty` через которые будете передавать нужные параметры и все. Как это сделать - вы написали, что знаете, также тут, на SO есть уйма вопросов про создания своих контролов. По этму вопрос как бы мне лично не понятен.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь